# Regular expression for not allowing spaces in the input field

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a username field in my form. I want to not allow spaces anywhere in the string. I have used this regex:

```
var regexp = /^\S/;
```

This works for me if there are spaces between the characters. That is if username is `ABC DEF`. It doesn't work if a space is in the beginning, e.g. `<space><space>ABC`.  What should the regex be?

Comment: Please show more code and describe what you *want*. Also, are you sure that you are using PHP? 'var ...' is more like Javascript.

Comment: @WillemMulder i am also using javascript

Answer (score 111, accepted):

While you have specified the [start anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) and the first letter, you have not done anything for the rest of the string. You seem to want [repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) of that [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) until the [end of the string](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html):

```
var regexp = /^\S*$/; // a string consisting only of non-whitespaces
```

Answer (score 17):

Use `+` plus sign (Match one or more of the previous items),

```
var regexp = /^\S+$/
```

Comment: You don't say why, and it doesn't matter anyway: the aim is to detect the presence of whitespace, we don't care how much of it there is.

Comment: @Rikesh still white spaces are not detected when we start typing with space

Comment: @AnazA - You can check at http://regexpal.com/ , its working fine. Seems there must be going something wrong at code side. If you can share more code of yours.

Answer (score 7):

If you're using some plugin which takes string and use construct Regex to create Regex Object i:e `new RegExp()`

Than Below string will work

```
'^\\S*$'
```

It's same regex @Bergi mentioned just the string version for new RegExp constructor

Answer (score 2):

This will help to find the spaces in the beginning, middle and ending:

`var regexp = /\s/g`

Comment: Hi Ashish Hundekar! I think the flag g is not necessary. /\s/ match the first Unicode whitespace character no matter where it is positioned in the string. I mean, with the flag is going to works anyway but it is dispensable.

Comment: Hi Pablo, actually yes it works but I had written if text area is present and we have to check multiple lines to find the whitespace character. In that case, **/g** can help.

Comment: In case the string be a multiline string /\s/g or /\s/ will be match the newline because a newline is considered a whitespace character see this example https://jsfiddle.net/Pablocattaneo/j2fkdy6o/1/

Comment: @Pablo, Thanks for sharing the example. Elaborating the point for mentioning **/g**. Consider for an example, if we have a string like 'abc def xyz', **/\s/** will match the first occurrence of whitespace after c at index 3 only whereas **/\s/g** will match all the occurrences of whitespaces after c and f at indices 3 and 7 respectively. I had given the generic solution. Simply **/g** is Global (Don't stop at first match, consider all matches).

Answer (score 0):

This one will only match the input field or string if there are no spaces. If there are any spaces, it will not match at all.

`/^([A-z0-9!@#$%^&*().,<>{}[\]<>?_=+\-|;:\'\"\/])*[^\s]\1*$/`

Matches from the beginning of the line to the end. Accepts alphanumeric characters, numbers, and most special characters.

If you want just alphanumeric characters then change what is in the [] like so:

`/^([A-z])*[^\s]\1*$/`