# How do I trim space in an input field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using an input field and when someone types in it they can add spaces as general behavior. I do not want anyone to add spaces into the field and even if someone adds one it should trim there and then.

Can someone please help on how to achieve this?

```html
<input type="text">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `trim()` function. This is destroys spaces.

```js
const inp = document.querySelector("#inp");

inp.addEventListener("input", function() {
  inp.value = inp.value.replace(' ', '');
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inp">
```

Comment: This does not work if the user right clicks and pastes text with a space into the text input field

Comment: @jones1008 I replaced the event with "input" and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

use the pattern attribute to specify a regular expression that enforces your no spaces rule. See below for examples

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp

Comment: I have seen your example and I'm still able to add spaces there. Here's the screenshot: https://prnt.sc/ol20ct

Comment: try a regular expression like "[a-zA-Z0-9]*" this means zero or more numbers or letters or maybe even this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16334765/regular-expression-for-not-allowing-spaces-in-the-input-field